# como puedo reconocer o seleccionar un radioButton en un addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, dom, radiobutton

Lo que quiero hacer es seleccionar o saber cuando el radioButton se le da click para realizar otra acción; es decir se hace visible el otro elemento.

```
   <input  type="radio"  id="rBtnYes" value="1"> yes
   <!--This element div in this moment it`s hidden -->
   <div id="visibleForm">Test</div>

  //js
    yesAssis.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var visibleForm =  document.getElementsByClassName('visibleForm');
    visibleForm.style.visibility = "visible" ; });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de seleccionar un `input` de tipo `radio`, por ejemplo,

Por su id

```
var radio = document.getElementById('rBnYes');
```

Por su etiqueta y tipo

```
var radio = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]');
```

Nota: querySelector devuelve el primer elemento, en este caso con etiqueta `input` y tipo `radio`.

Luego

```
radio.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  //Agrega aquí lo que quieras que se ejecute al hacer click
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias, no lo había encontrado como se hace.